# If ResourceDictionary is placed inside a UserControl that's on a ListBox DataTemplate, does it load it for each item?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary

To expand on the title question, here's the scenario:

Let's say I've got a UserControl I'm using for the primary text in a long list of items on a ListBox; each item is a DataTemplate on a ListBox with anywhere from tens to thousands of items (note: the List is virtualizing of course).

Inside this UserControl is a reference to all the resource dictionaries it needs, either put there in XAML like so:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
     <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
          ~Various other resource dictionaries~
     <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries/>
<ResourceDictionary/>
```

or put in the code behind of the user control like so:

```
public override void BeginInit()
{
    Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new ResourceDictionary().AddResource(~resource dictionary location here~));
    base.BeginInit();
}
```

**Are those resource dictionaries going to be brought in each and every time one of these user controls is loaded/initialized** in each and every listbox item, or is the compiler smart enough to see it already has the dictionary and will forgo spending resources to try and fetch the same thing over and over?

If the former is true, how much does it slow things down?

Comment: Put some object in one of the dictionaries and count how often it is instantiated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So think of it like this, if you start with one Resource Dictionary and declare another for it to inherit from via MergedDictionaries then at runtime it literally just injects a copy of that MergedDictionary into the one that it's declared in.

Now if you then plop that in an instance of say a DataTemplate being repeated than every instance of its repeating now has both those previous dictionaries injected in it because a DataTemplate is like its own little world. Which can quickly become a performance nightmare depending on the usage.

Hope this helps, cheers.

Comment: Does that mean it's less performance intensive to declare all styles in a merged dictionary in the app.xaml, or does that use too much memory, loading one massive dictionary right away?

Comment: If they're used often throw them in the application resources aka app.xaml but then again some instances are different so without seeing the overall requirement and what's being used it's hard to give a 100% best practice advice. There are some tools folks have made out in the wild to help mitigate the copying or dicts etc within wpf but I'd have to find them again.